# Not able to install requirement file because of wrapt error

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I am installing requirement file in using Virtualenv & got unexpected error of `wrapt`.

I have tried to find solution from google but not able to solve my issue.

Trackback of error is as below.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'd:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"
'"'C:\\Users\\admi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipeb0izl\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admi\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipeb0izl\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f
.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C
:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5dx2m136'
       cwd: C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\
  Complete output (59 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
  copying src\wrapt\decorators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
  copying src\wrapt\importer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
  copying src\wrapt\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
  copying src\wrapt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
  running build_ext
  building 'wrapt._wrappers' extension
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 101, in <module>
      run_setup(with_extensions=True)
    File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 71, in run_setup
      setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 25, in run
      build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 31, in build_extension
      build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 346, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 239, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
    File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1620, in return_env
      if self.vs_ver >= 14 and isfile(self.VCRuntimeRedist):
    File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
      st = os.stat(path)
  TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wrapt
  Running setup.py clean for wrapt
Failed to build wrapt
ERROR: django-cache-manager 0.5.1 has requirement Django<1.11, but you'll have django 2.2.6 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pyexcel-xlsx 0.5.7 has requirement openpyxl<2.6.0,>=2.5.0, but you'll have openpyxl 3.0.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, six, cryptography, idna, certifi, urllib3, chardet, requests, python-dat
eutil, PyJWT, adal, vine, amqp, anyjson, asgiref, asn1crypto, typed-ast, lazy-object-proxy, wrapt, astroid, backports.fu
nctools-lru-cache, soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, billiard, bitmath, boto, bson, pytz, more-itertools, zipp, importlib-metad
ata, kombu, celery, colorama, configparser, cron-descriptor, croniter, crontab, tzlocal, regex, dateparser, sqlparse, Dj
ango, django-cache-manager, django-js-asset, django-ckeditor, django-common-helpers, django-contrib-comments, django-cps
erver, django-crispy-forms, django-debug-toolbar, django-debug-panel, django-grappelli, Pillow, django-filebrowser, djan
go-mptt, django-mssql, jsonfield, django-post-office, pyodbc, django-pyodbc, unicodecsv, django-queryset-csv, future, dj
ango-ses, django-smtp-ssl, python-tds, django-sqlserver, django-storages, django-stronghold, django-tagging, psycopg2-bi
nary, ordered-set, django-tenant-schemas, django-widget-tweaks, django-xmlrpc, elasticsearch, enum34, et-xmlfile, future
s, webencodings, html5lib, huBarcode, isodate, isort, jdcal, jieba, json-table-schema, jsonpickle, lml, lxml, mccabe, py
thon-magic, xlrd, messytables, mots-vides, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, msrest, msrestazure, numpy, openpyxl, pandas, pd
fkit, psycopg2, ptvsd, pycryptodome, pyexcel-io, texttable, pyexcel, pyexcel-xlsx, pylint, pyparsing, pyStrich, pywin32,
 PyYAML, requests-toolbelt, singledispatch, SQLAlchemy, TextEncoder, uamqp, Unidecode, virtualenv, waitress, wfastcgi, x
lwt, xmltodict
    Running setup.py install for wrapt ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
'"'"'C:\\Users\\admi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipeb0izl\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admi\\A
ppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipeb0izl\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code
=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --recor
d 'C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1buc2ntu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compil
e --install-headers 'd:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\include\site\python3.7\wrapt'
         cwd: C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\
    Complete output (61 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\decorators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\importer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
    copying src\wrapt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wrapt
    running build_ext
    building 'wrapt._wrappers' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 101, in <module>
        run_setup(with_extensions=True)
      File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 71, in run_setup
        setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 25, in run
        build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipeb0izl\wrapt\setup.py", line 31, in build_extension
        build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 346, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Python37\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 239, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1620, in return_env
        if self.vs_ver >= 14 and isfile(self.VCRuntimeRedist):
      File "d:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
        st = os.stat(path)
    TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, set
uptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipeb0izl\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipeb0izl\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'
"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__,
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1buc2ntu\install-record.txt' --single-ve
rsion-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\production\sparrow_v2\venv\include\site\python3.7\wrapt' Check
the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ pip3 install wheel
```

worked for me,

regards!